# Where do I put the Main method?

Tags: java, methods, program-entry-point

I am new to Java and I am confused on where to place the Main method. I am still getting an error that reads "Could not find or load main class PuzzleJava.java"

I have tried to run numerous terminal commands and switch up the placement of the main method but I have had no luck.

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Arrays;
 import java.util.Collections;
 import java.util.Random;

 public class PuzzleJava{

     public static ArrayList<Integer> firstArray (){
         ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
         int[] myArray = {3,5,1,2,7,9,8,13,25,32};
         int sum = 0;
         for(int num : myArray){
             sum+=num;
             if(num>10){
                 numbers.add(num);
             }
         }
         System.out.println("Sum: "+sum);
         return numbers;

     }
      public static void main(String[] args){
         System.out.println(firstArray());
 }
```

I want this to be able to print out a new array of numbers greater than 10.

Comment: Your placement of `main` looks OK. I'm guessing your invocation of the java exe is the problem. How are you compiling your code and trying to run it?

Comment: Best to follow a tutorial that explains how to compile and run your first Java program... Like this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/index.html

Comment: I wonder how that compiles? You are missing a final bracket

Comment: You sound like you're running "java PuzzleJava.java".  That is not correct.  You need to compile your source to PuzzleJava.class and run "java PuzzleJava".  I'd reconsider the name of that class - just call it Puzzle.  You know it's Java.

Comment: => javac PuzzleJava.java and then
=> java PuzzleJava

Answer (score 0):

IDK what error you were getting but I think you are missing are curly bracket. It ran fine on my IDE.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PuzzleJava {

    public static ArrayList<Integer> firstArray() {
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int[] myArray = { 3, 5, 1, 2, 7, 9, 8, 13, 25, 32 };
        int sum = 0;
        for (int num : myArray) {
            sum += num;
            if (num > 10) {
                numbers.add(num);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
        return numbers;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(firstArray());
    } //<- you forgot this
}
```

output:

```
Sum: 105
[13, 25, 32]
```

These imports are not being used in the code snippet above that's why I removed it.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;
```

Comment: No, I am still getting the error, I do not understand.